# Why does this cause an error?

Tags: programming, warning-messages

```
 In[73]:= f[x_] := Save["C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file", x <> x]
 f["###"]
```

During evaluation of In[73]:= Save::sym: Argument ###:f3b5.01<>.01:f3b5###:f3b5 at position 2 is expected to be a symbol. >>

```
 Out[74]= Save["C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file", "###" <> "###"]
```

Comment: seems self explanatory, the second argument to `Save` should be a symbol, not a string.

Comment: The documentation says, *`Save["file", symbol]` appends definitions associated with the specified symbol to a file.*  What exactly did you expect `Save["file", "######"]` to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression x<>x evaluates to the STRING "xx", but the Save command only saves symbols, so Save["file",x] works fine and Save["file",x<>x] does not work. You can assign the result to  an expression and "Save" this expression.

Comment: Isn't everything in Mathematica an expression?

Comment: yes, @mgamer should have said `Save` only saves *symbol's*. It is an odd function, other things like `Export` will take general *expressions*

Comment: @george2079: You are so right! I meant "symbols" but (don´t know why) wrote expressions, so it was only clear from the context. I just edited it, thanks for your comment.